# Obtaining the other axis value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, graphics

I'm new at coding and I got this simple differential equiation and the plot of this function involved, I can obtain the value of the dependant variable based on the independant varible as usual, what I want to do now is to find a new value of the independant variable giving it the dependant variable based on the ploted graph, in other words I want to find y for a given x from the graph. this is my short code. Only half of it works.

```
Sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == Sqrt[a[t]], a[0] == 3}, a, {t, 0, 180}]
graph = Plot[a[t] /. Sol, {t, 0, 180}]
FindRoot[a[t] == 0.44 /. graph, {t, 0}] (*this is the part that doesn't work*)
a[t] /. Sol /. t -> 180
```

Any kind of help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks c:

Comment: Could you provide `a` definition?

Comment: How so? what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, it was my misunderstanding, you can't use `/. graph`, replace `graph` with `Sol`, you will get `{t -> -0.0163865}` which is out of bound and `a[-0.0163865] /. Sol` is around `{2.98117}`, technically you'd find a local minimum not the exact answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is use `WhenEvent` and `Reap` and `Sow`.(Also need to replace `0.44` to another number such as `10`).

```
{{sol}, {pts}} = 
 NDSolve[{a'[t] == Sqrt[a[t]], a[0] == 3, 
    WhenEvent[a[t] == 10, {Sow[t]}]}, a, {t, 0, 180}] // Reap
Plot[a[t] /. First@sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Point[({#, a[#]} /. sol) & /@ pts]}]
```

> `{{2.86045}}`

[image]

**Appendix**

The questioner's original approach.

```
sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == Sqrt[a[t]], a[0] == 3}, a, {t, 0, 180}]
graph = Plot[a[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 180}]
FindRoot[a[t] == 10 /. sol, {t, 
  0}] (*this is the part that doesn't work*)
a[t] /. sol /. %
```

> `{t -> 2.86045}`

> `{10.}`

Comment: i just want to read the graphic at another value i.e.30 in the Y axis what is in the X axis, from that same graph

Comment: {a'[t] == (0.16 - 0.0622 Sqrt[a[t]])/(Pi (a[t])^2), a[0] == 0.5} in this equation in it's graph, if i give it a value of 3 in the Y axis what it's the value on the X axis?

Comment: @Sosa `{{sol}, {pts}} = 
 NDSolve[{a'[t] == (0.16 - 0.0622 Sqrt[a[t]])/(Pi (a[t])^2), 
    a[0] == 0.5, WhenEvent[a[t] == 2.3, {Sow[t]}]}, a, {t, 0, 180}] //
   Reap
Plot[a[t] /. First@sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 180}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[({#, a[#]} /. sol) & /@ pts]}]`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use variable names with capital letters, those are used by the system. I corrected your syntax. Here is the working code. Note that the `FindRoot` gives warnings because the specified value is out of bounds:

```
sol[t_] = 
 a[t] /. NDSolve[{a'[t] == Sqrt[a[t]], a[0] == 3}, a, {t, 0, 180}][[1]]
graph = Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 180}]
FindRoot[sol[t] == 0.4, {t, 0}] 
sol[180]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I would take that in count